# How can I make emacs run inside the Cygwin terminal?

Tags: emacs, cygwin

On Windows 10, I have installed both emacs and cygwin, from their latest releases.

When in Cygwin terminal I run

```
$ emacs -nw
emacs: standard input is not a tty
```

How can I make emacs run inside the Cygwin terminal?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running cygwin emacs ?

Comment: No. I am running emacs installed for Windows. Is it possible to run that emacs in cygwin?

Answer (score 3):

Install Emacs for Cygwin.  Run the apropriate `setup` tool (as mentioned at https://cygwin.com/install.html) and select the Emacs package that you'd like to install. If you haven't installed Emacs before in Cygwin, choose "Not Installed" from the "View" and search for "emacs".

Comment: Thanks. I am running emacs installed for Windows. Is it possible to run that emacs in cygwin?